# Is it possible to use cin when using allocate to construct a string?

Tags: c++

I'm reading up on using allocators and one of the exercises asks to use an allocator to read user input from cin. Right now I create the string using a default constructor then read into the string, but I want to know if its possible to directly create the string with the input from cin?

Current Code:

```
int n = 1;
std::allocator<std::string> alloc;
auto p = alloc.allocate(n);
auto q = p;
alloc.construct(q);
std::cin >> *q;
```

Ideally:

```
alloc.construct(q, input from cin);
```

Comment: `std::cin` is a stream, you would need to pull chars one by one from it. Another thing you could do is `std::getline(std::cin, *q)` The only difference is that you would grab the whole input and not just a word.

Comment: @KillzoneKid, `std:getline(std::cin, *q)` is more along the lines of what I was thinking to remove the temporary string. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use of

```
std::cin >> *q;
```

does not look like a burden to me. I am not sure what's the motivation for wanting to use:

```
alloc.construct(q, input from cin);
```

Having said that, you can define a helper function.

```
template <typename T> T read(std::istream& in)
{
   T t;
   in >> t;
   return t;
}
```

Use it as:

```
int n = 1;
std::allocator<std::string> alloc;
auto p = alloc.allocate(n);
auto q = p;
alloc.construct(q, read<std::string>(std::cin));
```

Here's a [working demo](https://ideone.com/XGHfzo).

Comment: Obviously this reads into a `string` and then move-constructs the main string from that ;  I think the gist of the question was that they want to avoid having a temporary string too

Comment: @M.M, I can't think of a way to avoid the temporary. Can you?